# How do I perform binary addition on a mod type in Ada?

Tags: cross-platform, bit-manipulation, ada

Very specific issue here…and no this isn’t homework (left that far…far behind).  Basically I need to compute a checksum for code being written to an EPROM and I’d like to write this function in an Ada program to practice my bit manipulation in the language.

A section of a firmware data file for an EPROM is being changed by me and that change requires a new valid checksum at the end so the resulting system will accept the changed code.  This checksum starts out by doing a modulo 256 binary sum of all data it covers and then other higher-level operations are done to get the checksum which I won’t go into here.

So now how do I do binary addition on a mod type?

I assumed if I use the “+” operator on a mod type it would be summed like an integer value operation…a result I don’t want.  I’m really stumped on this one.  I don’t want to really do a packed array and perform the bit carry if I don’t have to, especially if that’s considered “old hat”.  References I’m reading claim you need to use mod types to ensure more portable code when dealing with binary operations.  I’d like to try that if it’s possible. I'm trying to target multiple platforms with this program so portability is what I'm looking for.

Can anyone suggest how I might perform binary addition on a mod type?

Any starting places in the language would be of great help.

Comment: Can you give an example of "binary addition"? What is the "binary sum" of 101b + 1110b?
Do you mean bitwise addition without carry? That would be XOR.
Or do you mean the arithmetical addition of two arbitrary length bit sequences?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to do 1's complement addition rather than 2's complement? (Like is done in the IP checksum algorithm - http://www.netfor2.com/checksum.html)?

Comment: no, told two's compliment specifically as this point

Comment: This is all I know: a simple 8 bit checksum which is the two's complement of the unsigned sum of the rest of the bytes in the rom modulo 256 such that if you sum up ALL the bytes including the checksum modulo 256, the result will be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a [modular type](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html), for which the operators do unsigned arithmetic.

```
type Word is mod 2 ** 16; for Word'Size use 16;
```

Addendum: For modular types, the predefined [logical operators](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-1.html#I2594) operate on a bit-by-bit basis. Moreover, "the [binary adding operators + and –](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-3.html#I2652) on modular types include a final reduction modulo the modulus if the result is outside the base range of the type." The [`function Update_Crc`](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Algorithms&CID=254) is an example.

Addendum: [§3.5.4 Integer Types, ¶19](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html) notes that for modular types, the results of the [predefined operators](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5.html) are reduced modulo the modulus, including the [binary adding operators + and –](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-3.html#I2652). Also, the shift functions in [§B.2 The Package Interfaces](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-B-2.html) are available for modular types. Taken together, the arithmetical, logical and shift capabilities are sufficient for most bitwise operations.

Comment: I don't really understand what he's asking for yet, but he already impiled he was using modular types.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Good point. I'm confidant that modular types are sufficient to implement any CRC. I'll look for an example.

Comment: OK, you're suggesting summation is defined for mod types in the way I want it...didn't see that note in the ARM.  OK then I'll try it!

Comment: @Josh - If the problem is as described in your comment on Hyperboreus' answer, then modular types should be just what you are looking for. Voting up TG's answer and comment based on that. However, I'm still confused as to exactly what you thought adding two of them would do that you don't want.

Comment: Ah. Well I thought the mod behavior might interfere with the final answer if I attempted to use +/- operators because I didn't see that section you linked to in the ARM when I looked up operators I didn't see a mention of mod types and became concerned that perhaps it was a class of operations I had to perform entirely through logical operators and became concerned.  Looks like this might have been a case of me confusing myself.  I was under the impression that with the change in behavior I might get an incorrect result.  I think everyone straightened it out for me.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: No problem. The note about binary adding operators is a special case of the behavior of predefined operators on modular types. I've tried to cite most of the reasons that modular types should do what you want.

Comment: @Josh - Well...the main reason that they should do what you want is that they were designed for just this purpose; unsigned math combined with bit twiddling.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Coming from Pascal some years ago, I recall being being disappointed with the (apparent) absence of (bit-mapped) sets, for which modular types are also just the thing. @Josh: Compare [sets](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-7.html).